# Ordering module build order IntelliJ for maven projects

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

How can I set an order to the build of multiple projects (modules) in IntelliJ?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you need to do this?

Comment: the order will be calculated by maven

Comment: I have a project that as multiple dependencies so the build order must reflect this, I can only build some modules after other are available in orther to artifact resolution can work as expected.

Comment: Please show the pom files..Apart from that if you have defined the dependency between the modules than the order will be done by Maven automatically.

Comment: It's needed because as far as I can tell IDEA doesn't follow exactly the same rules as maven does and so sometimes things that build fine with maven build in not quite the right order in IDEA. I actually fight with this all the time and am looking for a solution as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a multi-module maven project as described [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/maven-support.html#maven_multi_module) then you can set the build order by ordering the modules in your parent POM. [image]

Comment: I hate to say it, but intellij is so brain dead that for aggregator poms this is actually the case despite configuring an external maven instance and maven at the command line correctly ordering the reactor.

Answer (score 1):

On intellij click on the top toolbar

> > Run >> Edit Configurations...  >> click on the '+' symbol to "add New Configuration"

scroll down and pick  "Maven" it should open a window and by default the first tab "Parameters" is open.

down below in this window there is a divider called "Before launch" click on the arrow so it opens a field where you can click on the '+' symbol

This is where you can select "Run Maven Goal"
it will open a new window titled "Select Maven Goal"

working directory click on the far right button,  this is where you can select maven modules

and enter in command line  the maven command you would want to run e.g "install -f pom.xml"
you can add more maven goals  and the order is from top to bottom.

I am sorry I did not provide any images  I'll add them if anybody requests it in the comments

Answer (score -1):

1. Open run edit configurations.
2. Create a new Maven Runner.
3. Add All you Modules to the "Before launch" tab selecting "Run another configuration"

Comment: No way to add modules